# Como fechar menu responsivo ao clicar em um item e mudar o iframe em um arquivo html?

Tags: css, html5, css3, css-hover, css-transições

Estou usando um arquivo `index.html` que em uma tela larga aparece todos os itens do menu, mas ao ser redimensionado pra uma tela menor `(max-width: 640px)`, a barra de menu vira um ícone onde ao ser clicado aparece os itens do menu na tela menor.

Minha dúvida é: depois de clicar em um item gostaria que o menu da tela menor fechasse e ao mesmo tempo carregar um arquivo html dentro do iframe.

Obs.: Esse arquivo html que será carregado dentro do iframe é correspondente ao item do menu clicado.

Abaixo vai o código como exemplo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #555;
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

label[for="bt_menu"] {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 640px) {
  label[for="bt_menu"] {
    display: block;
  }
  #bt_menu:checked~.menu {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .menu {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    transition: all .2s;
  }
  .menu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  .icon {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="bt_menu">
<label for="bt_menu" class="icon">Menu</label>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="frame">Um</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="frame">Dois</a>
    <li><a href="#" target="frame">Tres</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="frame">Quatro</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<iframe src="#" name="frame" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi com esse javascript

```
function fechar() {

    var inputCheckbox = document.getElementById('bt_menu');

    if (inputCheckbox.checked === true) {
        inputCheckbox.checked = false;
    }

}
```

Dentro das tags `<a></a>`, inseri o evento `onclick="fechar()"` para chamar a função.

Funcionou!